# background-image :url(); not working

Tags: html, css

html:

```
<div id="banner">
  <h1>My Page</h1>
  <p>This is the important line everyone reads..</p>
  <a href="#">Enroll</a>
</div>
```

css:

```
#banner{
  background-image: url('https://usplash.it/1000/600/?random');/*problem is here*/
  padding: 150px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-size:cover;
  color: white;
}
```

background-image: url('https://usplash.it/1000/600/?random')

This is not displaying any image . Not only for this link but for all other links.

Only if the image is downloaded and the path is given there as a link, then it is working.

Comment: try to take off quotes: `background-image:url(https://usplash.it/1000/600/?random);`

Comment: @CBroe looks like link which is not working for me maybe

Comment: According to my browser, there is no DNS server found for `usplash.it`.

Comment: this is not working.:c @Banzay

Comment: Is there any alternative Link to generate random image like the above link.

Comment: This is the the link : https://unsplash.it/

Comment: http://placehold.it/1000x600

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like your link down is the cause. this one work

```css
#banner {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200);
  padding: 150px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  <h1>My Page</h1>
  <p>This is the important line everyone reads..</p>
  <a href="#">Enroll</a>
</div>
```

Comment: thank to you. I just heard there is something called `autogenerate random image url` like this :)

Comment: 'Is there any alternative Link to "generate random image" like the above link'...that was my question . Thanks for pinch.. :p @RizkiDPrast . If you not aware of the term please check https://unspalsh.it / .